# Equation containing Math.pow() producing unexpected results

Tags: java, math, double, java.util.scanner, equation

I am attempting to write a program which takes three inputs and puts them through the following equation:

`futureInvestmentValue = investmentAmount * (1 + monthlyInterestRate)^(numberOfYears*12)`

The correct example result I'm working from says that for `investment amount = 1000.56`, `annual interest rate = 3.25` (therefore `monthlyInterestRate = annual / 12`), and `numberOfYears = 1`, I should get `futureInvestmentValue = 1032.98`.

However, my program states a final result of "`$38045.96184617848`" (note: I am not required to round).

Why might this be occuring?

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class num2_21 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("This program was designed to calculate the future investment value of an investment. \n\n"
            + "When prompted, please enter the initial investment amount, interest APR (%), and length of investment (yrs). \n"
            + "Investment amount: ");
    Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    double investAmount = in1.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("\n" + "Annual interest rate in percentage: ");
    Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    double APR = in2.nextDouble();
    double monthlyInterest = APR / 12;

    System.out.println("\n" + "Length of investment: ");
    Scanner in3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    double investLength = in3.nextDouble();

    double futureInvestmentValue = investAmount * Math.pow((1 + monthlyInterest),(investLength*12));
    System.out.println("\n" + "Accumulated value: $" + futureInvestmentValue);


}

}
```

Console:

```
This program was designed to calculate the future investment value of an investment. 

When prompted, please enter the initial investment amount, interest APR (%), and length of investment (yrs). 
Investment amount: 
1000.56

Annual interest rate in percentage: 
4.25

Length of investment: 
1

Accumulated value: $38045.96184617848
```

**EDIT: I forgot to divide the APR by 100. I didn't realize I would need to convert it to a decimal. Apologies for the oversight. I appreciate the extra pairs of eyes. Thank you for your time.**

Comment: You forgot to divide you interest rate percentage by 100 to convert it to a decimal.

Comment: While you are at it: `monthlyInterestRate = annual / 12` What's that? Why don't I see any `(1 + a)` terms and twelfth roots?

Comment: @rgettman To convert it to a *fraction*. 'Convert it to a decimal' is meaningless. It already was decimal, and it has already been converted to a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that might be because annual interest rate of 425.0% isn't too bad, or it might be because you forgot to divide by 100:

```
    double APR = in2.nextDouble() / 100.0;
```